# How to determine HTTP Authorization mechanism used and how to decode it?

Tags: http, authentication, decode

I came through the below HTTP request header. I am confused what HTTP authentication mechanism is used and how to determine it. And, is it possible to decode the credentials from the below data alone? If so how?

Authorization: BankBasic EcLqpaoaqfNr8OhOuJl2w8wrXSI=

Answer (score 2):

HTTP authentication is defined in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7235.html, authentication schemes are registered at http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml.

"BankBasic" isn't registered, but there's some likelihood that it's the same as "Basic".